# Small question about condition in the Bouchala paper's 2005

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have this condition from this paper:  http://ejde.math.txstate.edu/Volumes/2005/08/bouchala.pdf (Strong resonance problems for the one-dimensional $p$-Laplacian. Bouchala, Jiri. Electronic Journal of Differential Equations (EJDE), Volume: 2005, page Paper No. 08, 10 p., electronic only.)

> $$ \forall v\in \ker(-\Delta_p-\lambda)\setminus\{0\}:\\(p-1)\int_0^{\pi} h(x) v(x)
>  dx< \underline{F(+\infty)}\int_0^{\pi} v^+(x) dx+\overline{
>  F(-\infty)}\int_0^{\pi} v^-(x) dx$$

where  $h\in L^{p'}(0,\pi),
 p'=\frac{p}{p-1}, p>1$ and $$F(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{p}{x}\int_0^x
 g(s) ds-g(x), x\neq 0\\ (p-1) g(0), x=0,\end{cases}$$

$g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, $v^+=\max\{0,v\}$ and $v^-=\min\{0,v\},$ and
$$\underline{F(+\infty)}=\liminf_{x\rightarrow +\infty} F(x) \qquad
 \overline{ F(-\infty)} =\limsup_{x\rightarrow -\infty} F(x) .$$

where in the paper prove that:

> $$\lim_{\|u_n\|\rightarrow+\infty}\int_0^{\pi} F(u_n)\frac{u_n}{\|u_n\|} dx=(p-1)\int_0^{\pi} h(x)v(x) dx$$ such that $\frac{u_n}{\|u_n\|}=v_n\rightharpoonup v$ (weakly) in $W^{1,p}_0$ and strongly in $C^0$

***My question:*** How can we conclude from this that $$\underline{F(+\infty)}>-\infty ~\text{and}~ \overline{F(-\infty)}<+\infty $$

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have given a correct url? This does not look like something from a paper on Abelian groups.

Comment: @MartinSleziak it is not a paper of Abelian groups

Comment: @MartinSleziak: http://ejde.math.txstate.edu/Volumes/2005/08/bouchala.pdf

Comment: I have made a mistake when copying. I looked at https://eudml.org/doc/12533 instead of https://eudml.org/doc/125333. (This shows that it is better if you make the link in your post clickable and include also some information about the paper.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak have you an idea please ?